# Map language "de-de" to "de" - play framework (1.2.x)

Tags: playframework

I want to use the messages.de file for the browser languages "de-de" and "de". I find it inconvenient to copy the content of messages.de to messages.de-de.

Is there a way to configure that one file is used for multiple languages?

Comment: If you are using Linux, creating a symbolic link may work

Comment: yes, that should work.